# SQL Reduction of 2 unique id columns

Tags: sql

I Have a table with these values:

> Id1, Id2 
>   1, 3 
>   2, 3 
>   1, 4 
>   2, 4

I want to reduce it so that its unique values in both columns

> Id1, Id2 
>   1, 3 
>   2, 4

How can i do this?

Comment: And what happens when you have a row with the values 3, 3?

Comment: The request does not really make sense.  It is unique based on the combination of the two columns.  If I understand what you are saying.  You probably want to select a distinct from column a, then in a different select get distinct from column b.  Then combine the two selects.  What you are describing would probably be better served by two tables.  Unless there is a relationship between Id1 and Id2 which there does not appear to be based on what you are saying.